# Using OutputStreamWriter to write binary char array

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create an array of 16-bit values to send over a socket in network order.

First, I have defined an array to hold the value:

```
char[] txbuf = new char[32]; // Java "char" is 16-bits
```

Next, I open the socket and create the OutputStreamWriter:

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
writer = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-16BE"));
```

Then I initialize the data to send:

```
txbuf[0] = 0x1234;
...
txbuf[31] = 0xFFFF;
```

Finally, I send the data to the socket:

```
writer.write(txbuf,0,32);
write.flush();
```

However, the device I am sending the data to is behaving erratically, and I suspect there is some issue with the UTF-16BE conversion actually doing something to the data (filtering characters out?) besides the simple network order translation.  Everything works fine in C, but not in the Java port.

I have seen various convoluted schemes for trying to write raw binary data but was trying for what seemed like the simplest and most straightforward method.

Is there a problem with the above scheme?

Comment: Are any of the characters you are writing surrogates? Have you looked at the actual data that is being sent?

Comment: @DavidConrad The data can be any random binary values.

Comment: @DavidConrad If I understand what you are saying, if any of the values are in the surrogate range (0xD800..0xDBFF / 0xDC00..0xDFFF) then some translation is going to occur?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually, but I think it's worth investigating.

Comment: Does the device really understand UTF-16BE? If not, you should be writing bytes, not chars. Don't use chars as though they are 16 bits on the wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write *bytes*, instead of characters, you should be using the raw `OutputStream` instead of a `Writer`.  `OutputStream` deals with bytes, `Writer` deals with characters, and a charset converts between them.

`DataOutputStream` writes primitive values to an `OutputStream` in big-endian order without any byte order marks or other charset issues.